# how to describe the distance of two bounded closed sets.

Tags: complex-analysis

We know that

> $A,B \subset \mathbb{C}$ are bounded closed sets.
>
> We define that:
>
> $d(A,B)=\inf_{z_1\in A,z_2\in B} |z_n-z_0|$

How to prove that

> $\exists z_1^*\in A,z_2^*\in B$
>   S.T.
>    $d(A,B)=|z_1^*-z_2^*|$

Can anybody give me an answer. Thanks very much.

Comment: Have you heard of compactness?

Comment: @uniquesolution is it means all the limits of sequence are in the set？

Comment: Yes, but it also means that every sequence in a compact set has a convergent subsequence. Now a closed and bounded set in $\mathbb{C}$ is compact, so what you want is to choose appropriate sequences in your set such that the infimum is their limit, and then take convergent subsequences.

Comment: @uniquesolution Thank you very much.

Comment: You look for a verb: it is "to reach". One would say that "the minimum is reached with $z_1=z_1^*$ and ..."